# Android and a call through to main thread from secondary thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a method in an object executing on a secondary thread. In the event that an error occurs, this method wants to tell the object's delegate to respond to this. The response must take place on the main thread (i.e. UI thread).

How do I call through to the main thread from my secondary thread? My object's class does not extend `Activity`, and I have no obvious `Activity` object at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Android handler. Here's an example

https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

Of course, you will have to pass the Handler into your 2nd thread somehow.

Comment: I went with `Handler` created in my root activity on the main thread where I hold a reference. One other catch was where to create a `Toast` I want to pop - I need access to a context via "this", but "this" doesn't make much sense in the secondary thread. This all seems a bit more complicated than it really need be, but that may just be me. Anyway, it works and it's not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable Context in the second class and then pass on the activity reference to this class in that variable.

Later you can use context in a similar way as activity.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few strategies to achieve that: AsyncTask, Handler, View.post(). They are all described in [painless threading article.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: Please don't post links to sites without a full explanation in your reply. Link is now broken and this answer has become useless

Comment: How about you start answering questions on your own instead of lecturing others how to answer questions? Or better, propose an edit to this answer with updated link - it was an official Android Developers article any you could find a new link with just a simple search: http://android-developers.blogspot.si/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Sorry If I came across as rude - wasn't intended. Just saying best to answer and back up answer with reference links. Thanks